# Obtain endpoint URL programatically inside wso2 custom handler

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I have a custom mediator which obtains the endpoint url from message context property ENDPOINT_PREFIX.

I am trying to do the same in my authentication handler, but the get property returns null.

Is there a different way to obtain this information inside a custom handler?

Note that I am not after the endpoint itself (e.g. /api/1.0.0) but after the url to which it points to (in the publisher ui it appears as production/sandbox url).

Comment: Maybe it's possible to obtain this from the API object?